# How to print JTable?

Tags: database, swing, jtable

I have a whole database shown in a `JTable` and I added a print button but what it does, is to convert the data in the `JTable` into a `.csv` file, commands excel to open it and the user can print it, but it looks pretty ugly. Is there a way to send a `JTable` component to printer?

Comment: Have you tried: [JTable.print()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#print()) ?

Comment: sounds like an intelligent button :-) Seriously, as the coder you should know what the button does (it's your code after all). If it should do something else, .. code it differently. BTW: the sidebar references similar questions which might be useful to study.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method under `JTable` called `print()`. Will save you alot. See below :-

```
package com.tanyasis.librarymanager;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.text.MessageFormat;

import javax.swing.JTable;

/**
 * Used to provide printing information and adding information that might be
 * important in a page such as page header, contents and footer. This class
 * makes sure that all contents of a table fit in the given page.
 * 
 * @author Tanyasis Mwanik
 * 
 */
public class PrintTable {

    private JTable table;
    private MessageFormat headerFormat, footerFormat;

    /**
     * Prints the table and provide post printing information to the user if it
     * was succesful
     * 
     * @param table
     *            <code>JTable</code> to be printed
     * @param tableTitle
     *            <code>String</code> to be used as the table header/title
     */
    public PrintTable(JTable table, String tableTitle) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.setTable(table);
        // Sets the table header
        headerFormat = new MessageFormat(tableTitle);
        // Sets the table footer
        footerFormat = new MessageFormat("Page {0}");

        try {
            boolean complete = table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH,
                    headerFormat, footerFormat, true, null, true, null);

            if (complete) {
                new ConfirmationClass(
                        "<html><h2>Records Printed Successfully</h2></html>");
            }

        } catch (HeadlessException | PrinterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the table
     */
    public JTable getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    /**
     * @param table
     *            the table to set
     */
    public void setTable(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MessageFormat header=new MessageFormat("Your Invoice");
                MessageFormat footer=new MessageFormat("Page");
            try 
            {

                table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer);
            }

            catch(Exception ae)
            { 
                System.err.println("Error printing: " + ae.getMessage());

                }
        }
    });
```

It might help :)

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I appreciate it & Thank You :)